# Single Controller, multiple (inherited) classes (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, single-table-inheritance

I have a base class inherited by 2 others via Single Table Inheritance. I want all subclasses to share the same controller/views for various reasons-the only real difference is in the model's functionality.

However, when I try to use **link_to "stuff", instance_of_child** I get complaints about being unable to find the correct page.

I've tried messing with **match '/subclass' => redirect('/parent')** but that yields weird links that make no sense. Any suggestions? I'm pretty new at rails, and I admit that my understanding of routes.rb is still limited-however, I'm not entirely sure that is even where I should be looking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails:

> If you’ve ever tried to add STI to an
>   existing Rails application you
>   probably know that many of your
>   link_to and form_for methods throw
>   errors when you add a parent class.
>   This is because ActionPack looks at
>   the class of an object to determine
>   its path and URL, and you haven’t
>   mapped routes for your new subclasses.
>   You can add the routes like so, though
>   I don’t recommend it:

```
# NOT recommended:
map.resources :cars,        :as => :vehicles, :controller => :vehicles
map.resources :trucks,      :as => :vehicles, :controller => :vehicles
map.resources :motorcycles, :as => :vehicles, :controller => :vehicles
```

> This only alleviates a particular
>   symptom. If we use form_for, our form
>   fields will still not have the names
>   we expect (eg: params[:car][:color]
>   instead of params[:vehicle][:color]).
>   Instead, we should attack the root of
>   the problem by implementing the
>   model_name method in our parent class.
>   I haven’t seen any documentation for
>   this technique, so this is very
>   unofficial, but it makes sense and it
>   works perfectly for me in Rails 2.3
>   and 3:

```
def self.inherited(child)  
  child.instance_eval do
    def model_name
      Vehicle.model_name
    end
  end
  super 
end
```

> This probably looks confusing, so let
>   me explain:
>
> When you call a URL-generating method
>   (eg: link_to("car", car)), ActionPack
>   calls model_name on the class of the
>   given object (here car). This returns
>   a special type of string that
>   determines what the object is called
>   in URLs. All we’re doing here is
>   overriding the model_name method for
>   subclasses of Vehicle so ActionPack
>   will see Car, Truck, and Motorcycle
>   subclasses as belonging to the parent
>   class (Vehicle), and thus use the
>   parent class’s named routes
>   (VehiclesController) wherever URLs are
>   generated. This is all assuming you’re
>   using Rails resource-style (RESTful)
>   URLs. (If you’re not, please do.)
>
> To investigate the model_name
>   invocation yourself, see the Rails
>   source code for the
>   ActionController::RecordIdentifier#model_name_from_record_or_class
>   method. In Rails 2.3 the special
>   string is an instance of
>   ActiveSupport::ModelName, in Rails 3
>   it’s an ActiveModel::Name

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Messing with the routing table seemed like a bad workaround, and yeah, I had noticed that it was messing up my forms. So, with just a slight modification to the example above to make it fit my class name, your solution resolved my troubles. You have no idea how much I was dreading creating/maintaining those extra controllers.